# Unity - Mover objeto mediante el Acelerometro en dispositivo

Tags: unity2d

tengo un problema ya que soy nuevo en unity, lo que deseo es que cuando el objeto alcance una determinada posición sobre el eje x se detenga, por ejemplo que cuando llegue a 2 o a -2 se detenga en ese punto. En el código que propongo cuando llega a esa posición se detiene y ya no avanza en sentido contrario. Saludos.

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    float temp = Input.acceleration.x;
    Mover (temp);
}

public void Mover(float temp){

    float posicion = 2.0f;

    if (transform.position.x > -posicion && transform.position.x < posicion) {
        transform.Translate (temp * velocidadPosicion * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, Space.World);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero que todavia necesites la ayuda.

La solucion seria hacer algo llamado Clamp a la posición en X del transform, Clamp es un metodo de Mathf que lo que hace es devolver un numero entre cierto rango.

Tu codigo deberia quedar algo así.

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    float temp = Input.acceleration.x;
    Mover (temp);
}

public void Mover(float temp){

    float posicion = 2.0f;
    transform.Translate (temp * velocidadPosicion * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, Space.World);

    //Clamp
    transform.position = new Vector3(Math.Clamp(transform.position.x, -2, 2), transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
}
```

Si no lo necesitas, Igual lo puedes marcar como verificado para que ayude a otros ;)

Comment: Excelente me ayudó, gracias

Comment: Con gusto, marco.